# How can I browse the unresolved references?

Tags: cross-referencing, emacs, warnings, auctex

When I compile with LaTeX (emacs+AUCTeX), I get the following warning:

```
LaTeX: there were unresolved references, {52} pages
```

I know that I have some `\ref{somefuturething}` here and there, and I would like to control them every now and then.

**How do I browse through the unresolved cross references in a big document (several files) in emacs AUCTeX?**

Comment: the log file will have a warning for each one so you just need to search the log for `Reference foo on page 5 undefined`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course, you're right :) Mind to post it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log file will have a warning for each one so you just need to search the log for `Reference foo on page 5 undefined`